"Sign in with Google" banner shows up even if one is signed in on the network but hasn't joined the site, and incorrectly in Firefox private mode
Right now when I visit any site that I don't have a profile on, I see the following:

This happens

on every site I don't have a profile even when I'm logged into my SE account
in private browsing mode in Firefox

It does not happen in incognito mode in Chrome.
The announcement mentioned that this should not appear in private browsing; obviously, the detection method is flawed here and SE should fix that.
I also don't think this should ever appear when you're already logged into SE. I know how to add a site to my SE account; I intentionally didn't create a profile on most SE sites. There is no reason to show me that annoying thing and force me to dismiss it individually on every site until it comes back.

Does this answer your question? Every SE site that I don't have an account for started prompting me for Google login

@MartinR No, I'm pointing out two specific behaviours I think are bugs.

@MadScientist The first of these two behaviors is already addressed in the linked post. That said, I'm reviewing to leave this open as a special case, since the staff member responding to that post was confused about it and tagged that post as deferred on that basis, and the second issue isn't addressed there.

I'd say it's the same, but meh, as this is so super annoying, perhaps having several similar reports will make some tiny difference, so not closing.

I assume that " not happen in incognito mode in Chrome" doesn't prove the Firefox behavior is a bug, it just proves that Google being Google has implemented special handling in its own browser so that other browsers give a "worse" experience. You know, those nice competition shaming moves that just happen to be outside the Antitrust Act
